# Add a 'Completed' Status to Lessons from a Course Subscription with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project for Online Classes, where users can Subscribe to a Course, for example:

1. I have Models for `Courses (name, description)`, `Lessons (courseId, title, video)` and `Subscriptions (courseId, userId)`
2. Courses Model has `has_many: lessons | has_many: subscriptions | has_many: users, through: :subscriptions`
3. Lessons Model have `belongs_to: course`
4. Subscription Model has `belongs_to: course | belongs_to: user`

What I need is when the current user (has subscriptions to a Course) clicks on a 'Complete & Continue' button after He/She watch the Lesson, add a status where the current Lesson get updated to 'Completed' and Keep track of that for every User subscribed to the Course.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What did you try, are you stuck at any point?

Comment: I'm thinking about how to start with this because first I thought to create a new Model with ```courseId, userId, lessonId, status```, but this has to be done for every Lesson on each Subscription I thought

Answer (score 0):

I would add an enum like so

in your chosen model class

```
Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:completed, :incomplete]
end
```

there is a great article [here](https://hackhands.com/ruby-on-enums-queries-and-rails-4-1/)

Hope that helps